# Count stuck at 7

Tags: python, loops, beautifulsoup

I am working on a project for school where I am creating a nutrition plan based off our schools nutrition menu. I am trying to create a dictionary with every item and its calorie content but for some reason the loop im using gets stuck at 7 and will never advance the rest of the list. To add to my dictionary. So when I search for a known key (Sour Cream) it throws and error because it is never added to the dictionary. I have also noticed it prints several numbers twice in a row as well double adding them to the dictionary.

edit: have discovered the double printing was from the print statement I had - still wondering about the 7 however

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3
import requests

url = "https://menus.sodexomyway.com/BiteMenu/Menu?menuId=14756&locationId=11870001&whereami=http://mnsu.sodexomyway.com/dining-near-me/university-dining-center"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html5lib")
allFood = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class':'get-nutritioncalculator primary-textcolor'})
allCals = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class':'get-nutrition primary-textcolor'})

nums = '0123456789'

def printData(charIndex):
    for char in allFood[charIndex].contents:
        print(char)

    for char in allCals[charIndex].contents:
        print(char)
def getGoals():
    userCalories = int(input("Please input calorie goal for the day (kC): "))   

#Display Info (Text/RsbPi)
fullList = {}
def compileFood():
    foodCount = 0
    for food in allFood:
        print(foodCount)
        for foodName in allFood[foodCount].contents:
            fullList[foodName] = 0
            foodCount += 1
            print(foodCount)
compileFood()
print(fullList['Sour Cream'])
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok first why is this happening:

The reason is because the food on the index 7 is empty. Because it's empty it will never enter your for loop and therefore never increase your foodCount => it will stuck at 7 forever.

So if you would shift your index increase outside of the for loop it would work without a problem.

But you doing something crude here.

You already iterate through the food item and still use an additional variable.
You could solve it smarter this way:

```
def compileFood():
    for food in allFood:
        for foodName in food.contents:
            fullList[foodName] = 0
```

With this you don't need to care about an additional variable at all.